# Can you get Windows raw input data immediately without WM_INPUT messages?

Tags: input, window, hid, wndproc

So can I get input data of a given device without the need to receive a WM_INPUT message altogether? Is there a function in Windows API that allows me to ask about the last input reading of a given device without involving a WNDPROC for message processing, and ideally without a window, and without device registration?

In an ideal scenario, I'd just look for the list connected devices, and ask for the input reading of the device I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (possibly overlapped - for async reads) `ReadFile` on a HID device file handle.
See [Obtaining HID Reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/obtaining-hid-reports) article and [HClient sample application](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-driver-samples/tree/main/hid/hclient) that is doing both - enumerating devices and reads from them. It is doing that without `WM_INPUT`/Raw Input API.